# Query caching in Rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using query caching for users controller index action.

```
def index
   @users = User.all
   json_response @users
end
```

I followed the rails cast videos and added like this in users controller.

```
   def index
     @users = User.cached_data
     json_response @users
   end
```

In users model I am adding cached_data method.

```
  def self.cached_data
   Rails.cache.fetch([])   // I am not getting how to do caching here and get all the users data
  end
```

Could someone please help me to Solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Most stuff on rails casts are ancient at this point. Refer to the [official guides instead](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make the Rails.cache.fetch into a block like this:

```
    def self.cached_data
      Rails.cache.fetch("all_users", expires_in: 2.hours) do
        # add your query here
        User.all
      end
    end
```

The cache_key can be anything you want and the expires_in: is optional, but I always add it in there unless the cache_key is based on a timestamp or something else that would automatically expire the cache.

Also, this documentation page is still valid:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

Comment: This answer is great and took ages to find. Helped me develop a very elegant solution for some frequently accessed queries on a gigantic table.